# When to use Sequence over List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Most Kotlin examples and real-world codebases I've seen perform operations over a regular list.

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val people = listOf(Person("John", 29), Person("Jane", 31))

    people.filter { it.age > 30 }.map { it.name }
}
```

What would be the real-world scenarios where it makes sense to use [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html#sequence-operations) over [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) or vice-versa?

```kotlin
people.asSequence().filter { it.age > 30 }.map { it.name }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intuition says sequences should be better for the performance as they focus on processing a single item fully before going to the next item. Processing of collections seems to be a huge waste of resources as we have to create multiple intermediary collections in the process.

However, reality is much different - both solutions have comparable performance and I believe potential differences are actually in favor of collections (Kotlin 1.8.x). There are several reasons for this:

- Collection processing is fully inlined, sequences require calling of lambdas.
- Implementation for collections is generally simpler, so there is less overhead.
- In some cases, e.g. `map()` we know the size of the resulting list upfront, so we can allocate the space for it. Sequences require copying of the data for growing.

Some of these problems could be addressed in the future by making possible to inline sequence processing. Then they should be generally superior in the terms of the performance. For now I would say collections are the default approach and we can use sequences in very specific cases, for example:

- Generating items on demand: generators, loading from the disk/network, infinite sequences, etc.
- If processing is resource-heavy, it requires some I/O, big amounts of memory, etc., we probably like to process a single item fully before going for the next one.
- If we use flat maps and then e.g. filter, then sequences allow to never keep all items in the memory at once. For example, we have a list of 1000 items, each flat maps to 1000 items, then we filter it which by average keeps only a single item per 1000. While using sequences we only keep a few thousands of items in the memory at any specific time. While using collections, we have to create a list of a million of items.
- If we need to observe the progress per-item and not per-stage.

There are probably more examples like this. Generally speaking, if you see a reason to process items one-by-one, sequences allow exactly this.